# How do increase the number of nested if else statements allowed by maven

Tags: java, maven

I have written my code to search if a node can be reached in a graph using java. I don't to change my code. I am using maven. When I try to compile it's giving me the error below.

```
[INFO] There is 1 error reported by Checkstyle 8.29 with com/github/ngeor/checkstyle.xml ruleset.
[ERROR] src/main/java/dsa/graphs/Graph.java:[160,25] (coding) NestedIfDepth: Nested if-else depth is 2 (max allowed is 1).
```

How do I get around this. I don't want to disable **checkstyle** at the same time I don't want to change my code. How can I increase that number to be more than 1.

Answer (score 3):

I am presuming that you have the checkstyle under com.github.ngeor package so just go to the file and change/add

```
<module name="NestedIfDepth">
  <property name="max" value="{AS_MUCH_AS_YOU_WANT}"/>
</module>
```

Or if you are referencing a checkstyle that is not under your control you can also override it.

Add the checkstyle plugin to your pom:

```
<plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <configLocation>checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
          <suppressionsLocation>checkstyle-suppressions.xml</suppressionsLocation>
          <suppressionsFileExpression>checkstyle.suppressions.file</suppressionsFileExpression>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

And of course you need to create checkstyle-surpressions.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 
<!DOCTYPE suppressions PUBLIC
     "-//Checkstyle//DTD SuppressionFilter Configuration 1.0//EN"
     "https://checkstyle.org/dtds/suppressions_1_0.dtd">
 
<suppressions>
  <suppress checks="NestedIfDepth"
            files="Graph.java"
            lines="{what_Lines_you_need}"/>
</suppressions>
```

This will